# Event Handler not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, event-handling

I'm making a chat similar to the Facebook's or Gmail's one, but something is just not working. If I have 5 conversations opened, just one works and just one shows/hides. You can see it in [live-pin.com](http://live-pin.com). It would be useless if I paste a piece of code since it's all involved, I would need to paste all my site!

But here's a little bit of chat code

```
function getOnJSON(){
    var from;var to;var msg_id;var msg_txt;var new_chat_string;

    //Getting the data from the json file
    $.getJSON("/ajax/end.emu.php",function(data){
    $.each(data.notif, function(i,data){
        from = data.from;to = data.to;msg_id = data.id;msg_txt = data.text;
        if ($("#chat_"+from+"").length === 0){
            $("#boxes").append('<div id="chat_'+from+'" class="chat_box hidden_box">'+
                '<div id="'+from+'_nick" class="chat_nick">'+from+'</div>'+
                '<ul id="'+from+'_txt" class="chat_txt">'+
                    '<li id="'+msg_id+'_txt_msg" class="chat_txt_msg">'+ msg_txt+'</li>'+
                '</ul>'+
                '<form class="new_message" method="POST" id="new_msg_'+from+'">'+
                    '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your message..." id="'+from+'_input" class="new_input" name="post_text" />'+
                    '<input type="hidden" name="to" value="'+from+'" />'+
                        '</form>'+
                        '</div>');    
            $('#new_msg_'+from).submit(submitChatMsg);
            $('#'+from+'_txt').jScrollPane({stickToBottom: true});
            $('#'+from+'_nick').live("click", function(){ toggleChat('#chat_'+from); });
            // $('#boxes').delegate('.chat_nick', 'click', function() { toggleChat('#chat_'+this.id.replace('_nick', '')); });
            $('body').append('<embed src="http://cdn.live-pin.com/assets/pling.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');

        }else{
            var pane2api = $('#'+from+'_txt').data('jsp');
            var originalContent = pane2api.getContentPane().html();
            pane2api.getContentPane().append('<li id="'+msg_id+'_txt_msg" class="chat_txt_msg">'+ msg_txt+'</li>');
            pane2api.reinitialise();
                $('embed').remove();
            $('body').append('<embed src="http://cdn.live-pin.com/assets/pling.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
        }
    });
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:** Fixed the show/hide problem. Now the main problem is that just 1 of the multiple forms `.new_message` are submited, they use `AJAX` to `POST` the message but just the last created works. They are all created dynamically and have a different ID assigned.

```
$('.new_message').live('submit',function(){
    contactForm = $(this);
    valor = $(this + 'input:text').val();
    destinatary = $(this + 'input[type=hidden]').val();
    reponse_id = destinatary + "_input";
    if (!$(this + 'input:text').val()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/end.emu.php?ajax=true",
            type: contactForm.attr('method'),
            data: contactForm.serialize(),
            // success: submitFinished
            success: function(data){
                responsed = $.trim(data);
                if (responsed != "success") {
                    alert("An error occured while posting your message");
                }else{
                    $('#' + reponse_id).val("");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: You can't just debug-step through your javascript in Firebug and see what happens/goes wrong? Or do you want someone else to do that for you?

Comment: What event handler? Can you narrow it down for us to just the relevant code?

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann I did it and doesn't works!

Comment: @PeeHaa, neither form (new_msg) nor `toggleChat()`

Comment: @Luis I don't see `toggleChat` being called anywhere nor do I see form(new_msg) anywhere.

Comment: Form `.new_message` and `toggleChat()` is called from `$('#'+from+'_nick').live("click", function(){ toggleChat('#chat_'+from); });
`

Comment: I think you can use a different approach to make it easy, i.e. use a class for all of your chat box and declare a function like $('.chatBox').live('click', function(e){ toggleChat($(this)); }); inside ready event and toggle function should be function toggleChat(obj){ //do something with obj }

Comment: @Heera GUY! Exceptional! please put it as an aswer so I can give you the points, no one could do this before. Can you help me now with the form problem?

PS: I fixed it with `$('.chat_nick').live('click', function(e){ toggleChat('#chat_'+this.id.replace('_nick', '')); });`

Comment: Answered it, what about form ? please make it clear.

Comment: Enter to the site and see it, just one of the 2/more boxes input "new message" works, seen it?

Comment: I just updated the question in order to be easier to understand @Heera

Comment: Did you mean that chat box's message doesn't submit but the last one ?

Comment: Where is your form submit code ?

Comment: @Heera yes, exactly that happen, I updated with the code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7595/discussion-between-heera-and-luis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $('.chatBox').live('click', function(e){ toggleChat($(this)); });
        function toggleChat(obj)
        {
            current_margin = obj.css('bottom');
            if (current_margin == "0px"){
                obj.animate({bottom : "-270px"});
            }
            else
            {
                obj.animate({bottom : "0px"});
            }
        }
```